# Is there a way to "inject" pure CSS into MUI v5

Tags: material-ui

I have a custom spinner that is currently using keyframes like so:

```
import { keyframes } from "@mui/system";
...
const keyframeSpinner = keyframes`
  0%{transform:rotate(0deg);}
  100%{transform:rotate(360deg);}
`;
...
<Box
  sx={{
    animation: `${keyframeSpinner} 1s linear infinite`,
  }}
/>
...
```

I don't want to import @mui/system and I don't want to use styled components.

So, I'm trying to find a solution where I can uses pure css or another solution that I'm unaware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily apply in-line CSS styles to components using [emotion](https://emotion.sh/docs/css-prop), which is also used by MUI.

For example, here is the `css` prop from `emotion` being used to customize `background-color` and `hover` on a `div`. The code you write in the `css` prop can be pure CSS.

```
import { css, jsx } from '@emotion/react'

const color = 'darkgreen'

const customCss = css`
  background-color: hotpink
  &:hover { color: ${color} }
`

render(
  <div css = {customCss}>
    This div has a hotpink background.
  </div>
)
```